# How do i abstract TChild from Parent<TParent,TChild>

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, interface

I have 2 interfaces which use generic

my child interface looks like:

```
public interface ICell<TContent>
{
    TContent Content { get; }

    string Background { get; }
    string Foreground { get; }

}
```

and my Parent interface like:

```
public interface IRow<TRowHeader,TContent>
{
    TRowHeader RowHeader { get; }

    IList<ICell<TContent>> Zellen {get;}
}
```

when i create a class based on IRow i have to set the `TContent` which i want to avoid. So i would like to know how to abstract this generic away from my `IRow`?

in the end i want to be able to write

```
public class MyCell : ICell<string>
{
    public string Background { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Foreground { get; set; }
}

public class MyRow: IRow<string,MyCell>
{
    public string RowHeader { get; set; }
    public IList<MyCell> Zellen { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a different interface then, you can't just omit generic arguments and substitute concrete classes. Why would you not do something like `MyRow : IRow<string, MyCell>`?

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks i will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do what you are asking, you have to change your `IRow` interface a little bit:

```
public interface IRow<TRowHeader, TCell>
{
    TRowHeader RowHeader { get; }

    IList<TCell> Zellen { get; }
}
```

What is happening is that you need to identify that the `IList` can hold a type `TCell`. The thing you can't do here say that `TCell` is an `ICell<T>` (because you would have to define `T` in the type list), but you can add another interface and do this:

```
public interface ICell 
{ 
    string Background { get; }
    string Foreground { get; }
}

public interface ICell<TContent> : ICell
{
    TContent Content { get; }
}
```

Which would allow you to create a constraint on the `IRow` `TCell` type:

```
public interface IRow<TRowHeader, TCell> where TCell : ICell
{
    TRowHeader RowHeader { get; }

    IList<TCell> Zellen { get; }
}
```

Now, you can define your `MyRow` class

```
public class MyRow : IRow<string, MyCell>
{
    public string RowHeader { get; set; }
    public IList<MyCell> Zellen { get; set; }
}
```

And the constraints are all satisfied.

This is a little bit long-winded and it would be nice if you could just forego the non-generic `ICell` and specify that `ICell<T>` where `T` is any type in the constraints for `IRow`, but at this point in C# its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is : 
- A cell has a generic content (TContent)
- A row is a List of Cells (TCell). TCell itself can be generic.

So you code look like this :

```
public interface ICell<TContent>
{
    TContent Content { get; }

    string Background { get; }
    string Foreground { get; }
}
public interface IRow<TRowHeader,TCell>
{
    TRowHeader RowHeader { get; }
    IList<TCell> Zellen {get;}
}
```

And then,

```
public class MyCell : ICell<string>
{
    public string Background { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Foreground { get; set; }
}

public class MyRow: IRow<string,MyCell>
{
    public string RowHeader { get; set; }
    public IList<MyCell> Zellen { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The only issue here is that inheritors of `IRow` could do something like this: `public class MyNewRow : IRow<string, int> { ... }` and it be perfectly legal code. Nothing is saying that `TCell` must be an `ICell<T>`.